# R: Hat matrix in ridge regression using glmnet package

Tags: r, glmnet, coefficients

I am working with *glmnet* package (R) and I need to extract hat-matrix for ridge regression in order to test coefficient's significance. I've looked up the documentation and the source code of the function *glmnet*, but I found no clues about how to get to this matrix. Does anybody know if it's possible, using this particular package?